# Saving an object into the session or cookie

Tags: laravel, instagram-api

I'm using [Instagram API library](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API) to connect user to Instagram profile and then do smth with it. So, as Instagram API wiki says:

> Once you have initialized the InstagramAPI class, you must login to an account.
>
> ```
> $ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram(); 
> $ig->login($username, $password); // Will resume if a previous session exists.
> ```

I have initialized InstagramAPI class and then I called `$ig->login('username', 'password');`. But I have to call it in every function where I need to work with Instagram.

So how could I save this object `$ig` for using it in the future in other controllers without calling `login()` any more? Can I save `$ig` object into the session or cookie file?

P.S. I think saving into the session is not safe way to solve the issue.

**UPD**: I was trying to save `$ig` object into the session, however the size is  large and session become stop working as well.

Comment: Why not just call `login` every time? What you want doesn't seem like a same way to use an external API.

Comment: Why don't save in Service container? Ex: `App::instance($ig)`. Probably make a service provider for that class to be resolved from.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, because It was a few acident when user got block because of lots of requests..

Comment: @TheAlpha, can you say more about it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers

Comment: @TheAlpha, hmm. I really do not know how to do that. Can you help me  with just `register` method in Provider file?

Comment: @entithat, provided an answer, as per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `register` method you asked in the comments section, all you need to create a new [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers) class in your `app\providers` directory and declare the `register` method in there for example:

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use InstagramAPI\Instagram;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class InstagramServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        // Use singleton because, always you need the same instance
        $this->app->singleton(Instagram::class, function ($app) {
            return new Instagram();
        });
    }
}
```

Then, add your newly created `InstagramServiceProvider` class in `providers` array inside the `config/app.php` file for example:

```php
'providers' => [
    // Other ...
    App\Providers\InstagramServiceProvider::class,
]
```

Now on, in any controller class, whenever you need the `Instagram` instance, all you need to call the `App::make('InstagramAPI\Instagram')` or simply call the global function `app('InstagramAPI\Instagram')` or even you can `typehint` the class in any method/constructor etc. Some examples:

```
$ig = App::make('InstagramAPI\Instagram');
$ig = App::make(Instagram::class); // if has use statement at the top fo the class
$ig = app('...');
```

In a class method as a dependency:

```
public function someMethod(Instagram $ig)
{
    // You can use $ig here
}
```

Hope this helps but read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers) properly, there will get everything documented.

Comment: I have a question. If providers load at the start, so how can I get users's name and password (via login form) and then put it into the `register` method..? If I will call singleton without user data it won't be working..

Comment: You'll call `app('InstagramAPI\Instagram')->login(...)`.

Comment: yes, I know. But `login` method returns `null`. So Can I create Instagram object and then call login function and then return Instagram object, not login method?

Comment: FYI, by registering the `InstagramAPI\Instagram` as a singleton into the container, you are telling the framework that, '"Hey, whenever I ask for 'InstagramAPI\Instagram', please gimme the same instance I registered."

Comment: OK, I understood. Thanks:)

Comment: One more question. I need to use this line `Instagram::$allowDangerousWebUsageAtMyOwnRisk = true;`, but when I write it into the InstagramProvider it does not work. What I can do with it? And how to save user's login?  :(

Comment: Anddd when I call InstProvider in InstagramController and then call `login` function I want to save this object. But when I call InstagramProvider (`app(Instagram::class)`) I get new (clear) object... **Thank you a lot :D**

Comment: No, if you use singleton to register it then you should get the same object. About the login, I didn't use that api so can't tell you anything about that.